# TinyMCE plugin to create how rows of table

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, rte

Is there a way to create a plugin for tinymce that creates a custom HTML layout based on what the user enters into input boxes to create the HTML?

For example at the moment I use the "template" plugin which creates this example HTML and the user has to copy/paste the HTML for how ever many list items he wants:

```
<ul>
<li><strong>Attribute Name</strong> Attributes description.</li>
<li><strong>Attribute Name</strong> Attributes description.</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to add something like this to a popup plugin which automatically generates the `<li>` for each of the attributes that the user inserts.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of such a plugin. Looks like you will have to develop something on your own. You may start here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin